# xdebug and WAMP will connect, but not when using Flash

Tags: php, flash, netbeans, wamp, xdebug

I've read a lot of xdebug / WAMP / NetBeans won't connect messages, but so far they haven't helped.

I've got a php test project that connects to netbeans-xdebug, and lets me break, step, watch variables, and other good stuff.

I did that to test the environment.  The local site I want to develop with is an ActionScript 3.0 site with php handlers.  I was hoping I could simply point to the src directory, set my URL to http://localhost/TestInterface.swf, and then hit breakpoints as I did earlier.  Unfortunately I'm seeing a seemingly unending "Waiting for Connection (netbeans-xdebug)" message at the bottom of the NetBeans IDE and no breakpoints.

When using IE11, the flash app continues to work while "Waiting for Connection", and no breakpoints are hit.  My php test project hits breakpoints.

When using Chrome with the NetBeans connector, same thing for both.

My php code is running directly, the URL ends with test.php.  My flash code is running flash, and using POST to execute the php scripts.  I feel like I'm not directly connecting to the code as far as xdebug is concerned, but I'm still too new to this architecture to know for sure if that's the case, and if so what to do about it.

If anyone has any insights they could share, I'd appreciate it.  When I include flash or actionscript in my search for this, it comes up empty.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose something is mysteriously wrong with my system.  However, I stopped using IE and Chrome and switched to Firefox, and it's all working as expected.